# Obtain name of file created by parquet() function of DataFrameWriter class?

Tags: pyspark, parquet

I'm using PySpark code to create a parquet file; specifically, I'm using the parquet() function of the DataFrameWriter class and providing just the location, not the name of the parquet file. I'd like to know the name of the parquet file that was created; however, the function returns None. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Files' name created by `DataFrameWriter` are unpredictable, because of the nature of distribution work (i.e. multiple workers is writing in the same location). However, you can retrieve the file name using [`input_file_name`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name) when re-read those parquet files.